# Advice for loading application options

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, persistence

I want to create a WinForms application.
This application will have many configurable options that will be saved in a database, so they can be persisted across executions (e.g. print settings, design options, etc.).

What approach would you recommend for loading these options, to avoid frequent access to the database?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a problem reading from the database? Your problem is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it security isn't important, you could also have the settings saved in an xml file that your form reads in.  You could have a class that loads the properties that you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

```
[Serializable()]
public class Defaults
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Tolerance { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
 }

internal class FormDefaults
{
public void LoadSettings()
    {
      string kfileString = @"C:\Default_Settings.xml";

      var q = from el in XElement.Load(kfileString).Elements()
                select new FormDefault()
                {
                    Description = el.Element("InstrumentDescription").Value,
                    Tolerance = Double.Parse(el.Element("InstrumentMassTolerance").Value),
                    Units = el.Element("InstrumentMassUnits").Value,

                };
        }
    }
}
```

That's pretty rough but I had something similar that worked pretty well and was pretty easy to set up.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems, the settings saved in the database  will be shared by all the users. In this case you have think about having settings for each user. Better option would be saving in the local config file which can be encrypted and used. If anything needs to shared across users then can use db for that particular option. You can load those option before application loads and access it through objects.

You can do these database fetch operations in the SPlash screen by showing progress to the users.